# SQL return row based on a value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has contains Fees.  Each fee has a status.  When a user changes the quantity of a fee, the original row is marked as Ready For Delete (status changed to Ready For Delete) and a new row is created with the quantity just entered by the user.  This new row is then given a status of Paid.  A supervisor needs to verify the fee change and once they do once, the status of the original fee row is updated to Deleted.  what I'm trying to do is when a fee has been amended..if the status of the original fee is Ready for Delete and the new fee status is Paid, return the Ready for Delete.  When the original fee status is Deleted and the new fee status is Paid, return the Paid fee.  I've tried using

```
select ISNULL(b.StatusId, c.StatusId) id
from  (
  select *
  from  FeeItem 
  where Status = Paid) b

left join (
  select *
  from  FeeItem 
  where Status = Ready For Delete) c
on b.FormId = c.FormId
```

but that's wrong.  Any help pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful here. Please can you provide them?

Comment: String constants should be in single quotes.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select *
From (Select 
    t.*,
    Row_number() over (partition by formid 
         order by Case status
           when 'ready for delete' then 1
           when 'paid' then 2 else 3 end) rn
From feeitem t) t
Where rn = 1;
```